# Properties pad doesn't work on Visual Studio 2019 for Mac

Tags: xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-mac

Properties pad doesn't work on my Visual Studio 2019 on Mac.

[Attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePxhG.png)

I tried it on tools like Button or Label. I restarted visual, closed and opened files and nothing has changed.
On this video: https://youtu.be/76it8xVANbI?t=137 it looks fine but my properties pad doesn't display anything inside xaml file. When I click on filenames on the solution pad, properties pad displays info about those files.

Comment: Which version of  Visual Studio 2019 for Mac are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just searched the document and found this feature exists in [Visual Studio 2019 for Mac version 8.4 Preview 1 (8.4.0.1935)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2019-mac-preview-relnotes#--visual-studio-2019-for-mac-version-84-preview-1-8401935)

There says:

> **Xamarin:**
>
> You can now use the Properties panel to change your control's
> attributes when editing Xamarin.Forms XAML. To open it, go to **View** >
> **Pads** > **Properties**.

So you can update your Visual-Studio for Mac to `version 8.4 Preview 1 (8.4.0.1935)` to use this feather.